# PySpark Grouping keys with a catch that one key in a column might group with multiple keys in another column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, python-dedupe

I have a pyspark dataframe as below:

```
data = [
    ['7933546917973caa8c2898c834446415', '3ef2e38d48a9af3e096ddd3bc3816afb', 1],
    ['7d693086c5b8f74cbe881166cf3c2a29', 'fcb907411aff4f44c599cf03d23327c0', 2],
    ['7e18b452bb1e2845800a71d9431033b6', '9bc9d06e0efb16abde20c35ba36a2f1b', 3],
    ['7e18b452bb1e2845800a71d9431033b6', 'ff351ada316cbb0f270f935adfd16ad4', 4],
    ['8240cf1e442a97aa91d1029270728bbb', '484f25e9ab91af2c116cd788c91bdc82', 5],
    ['8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9', '8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987', 6],
    ['8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9', '9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622', 7],
    ['8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987', '9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622', 8],
    ['8f459a7cff281bad73f604166841849e', '41f007c0cc45c228e246f1cc91145878', 9],
    ['99f70106443a6f3f5c69d99a49d22d01', 'be73ca52536d13dfea295d4fcd273fde', 10],
    ['a9781767ca4fe8fb1282ee003d2c06ac', 'cb6feb2f38731fc7832545cbe2ac881b', 11],
    ['f4901968c29e928fc7364411b03336d4', '6fa82a51f17f0bf258fe06befc661216', 12],
    ['f6da014449e6fa82c24d002b4a27b105', '41f007c0cc45c228e246f1cc91145878', 13],
    ['f6da014449e6fa82c24d002b4a27b105', '8f459a7cff281bad73f604166841849e', 14],
    ['f93c0028bb26bc9b99fca1db300c2ac1', 'ccce888c5813025e95434d7ceedf1db3', 15],
    ['ff351ada316cbb0f270f935adfd16ad4', '9bc9d06e0efb16abde20c35ba36a2f1b', 16],
    ['ffe20a2c61638bb10bf943c42b4d794f', '985e237162ccfc04874664648893c241', 17],
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['id1', 'id2', 'grp'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

The result I want is this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|ID                                                                                                    |grp|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[7d693086c5b8f74cbe881166cf3c2a29, fcb907411aff4f44c599cf03d23327c0]                                  |2  |
|[7933546917973caa8c2898c834446415, 3ef2e38d48a9af3e096ddd3bc3816afb]                                  |1  |
|[8240cf1e442a97aa91d1029270728bbb, 484f25e9ab91af2c116cd788c91bdc82]                                  |5  |
|[8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987, 9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622, 8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9]|8  |
|[8f459a7cff281bad73f604166841849e, 41f007c0cc45c228e246f1cc91145878, f6da014449e6fa82c24d002b4a27b105]|9  |
|[99f70106443a6f3f5c69d99a49d22d01, be73ca52536d13dfea295d4fcd273fde]                                  |10 |
|[a9781767ca4fe8fb1282ee003d2c06ac, cb6feb2f38731fc7832545cbe2ac881b]                                  |11 |
|[f4901968c29e928fc7364411b03336d4, 6fa82a51f17f0bf258fe06befc661216]                                  |12 |
|[ffe20a2c61638bb10bf943c42b4d794f, 985e237162ccfc04874664648893c241]                                  |17 |
|[ff351ada316cbb0f270f935adfd16ad4, 9bc9d06e0efb16abde20c35ba36a2f1b, 7e18b452bb1e2845800a71d9431033b6]|16 |
|[f93c0028bb26bc9b99fca1db300c2ac1, ccce888c5813025e95434d7ceedf1db3]                                  |15 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

The grp is not set defined that it should be the same.

Basically the requirement is that all the keys like:

```
['8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9', '8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987', 6],
['8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9', '9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622', 7],
```

should come in one array like:

```
['8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987', '9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622', '8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9']
```

so far I have been able to get to here:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|ID                                                                                                    |grp|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[7933546917973caa8c2898c834446415, 3ef2e38d48a9af3e096ddd3bc3816afb, NULL]                            |1  |
|[7d693086c5b8f74cbe881166cf3c2a29, fcb907411aff4f44c599cf03d23327c0, NULL]                            |2  |
|[7e18b452bb1e2845800a71d9431033b6, 9bc9d06e0efb16abde20c35ba36a2f1b, NULL]                            |3  |
|[7e18b452bb1e2845800a71d9431033b6, ff351ada316cbb0f270f935adfd16ad4, NULL]                            |4  |
|[8240cf1e442a97aa91d1029270728bbb, 484f25e9ab91af2c116cd788c91bdc82, NULL]                            |5  |
|[8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9, 8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987, NULL]                            |6  |
|[8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9, 9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622, NULL]                            |7  |
|[8dc7dfb4466590375f1aaac7fc8cb987, 9b93e3cfc5605e74ce2ce4c9450fd622, 8919d5fd5b6fd118c1c6b691c65c9df9]|8  |
|[8f459a7cff281bad73f604166841849e, 41f007c0cc45c228e246f1cc91145878, f6da014449e6fa82c24d002b4a27b105]|9  |
|[99f70106443a6f3f5c69d99a49d22d01, be73ca52536d13dfea295d4fcd273fde, NULL]                            |10 |
|[a9781767ca4fe8fb1282ee003d2c06ac, cb6feb2f38731fc7832545cbe2ac881b, NULL]                            |11 |
|[f4901968c29e928fc7364411b03336d4, 6fa82a51f17f0bf258fe06befc661216, NULL]                            |12 |
|[f6da014449e6fa82c24d002b4a27b105, 41f007c0cc45c228e246f1cc91145878, NULL]                            |13 |
|[f6da014449e6fa82c24d002b4a27b105, 8f459a7cff281bad73f604166841849e, NULL]                            |14 |
|[f93c0028bb26bc9b99fca1db300c2ac1, ccce888c5813025e95434d7ceedf1db3, NULL]                            |15 |
|[ff351ada316cbb0f270f935adfd16ad4, 9bc9d06e0efb16abde20c35ba36a2f1b, 7e18b452bb1e2845800a71d9431033b6]|16 |
|[ffe20a2c61638bb10bf943c42b4d794f, 985e237162ccfc04874664648893c241, NULL]                            |17 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

using below logic (very inefficient):

```
df.alias('df1')\
    .join(df.alias('df2'), (F.col('df1.ID1') == F.col('df2.ID2')), 'left')\
    .select(F.array_distinct(F.array(F.col('df1.ID1'), F.col('df1.ID2'), F.col('df2.ID1'), F.col('df2.ID2'))).alias('ID'), F.col('df1.grp') )\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining two pyspark dataframes where df1 column is ArrayType and df2 is IntegerType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068032/joining-two-pyspark-dataframes-where-df1-column-is-arraytype-and-df2-is-integert)